# retrieve HSQLDB schema through java

Tags: java, hsqldb

I want to retrieve HSQLDB table schema through the java code. Please help me to how can I do this.

Comment: You need to be way more specific. What exactly do you mean with "retrieve table schema"? Please give us some examples with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JDBC you can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html to obtain meta data programmatically. See also this tutorial: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/databasemetadata.html